# Order entries by custom time field

Tags: entries, order

I've got an events listings which works pretty well and there is a:

- Custom Date field, eventEnd (just date)
- Custom Start Time, eventStart (just time)
- Custom End Time, eventEnd (just time)

I can list these entries so we list by date then time by using:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('events').order('eventDate', 'eventStart').find() %}
```

but eventStart is ignored altogether, even when I would use:

```
{% for entry in craft.entries.section('events').order('eventStart').find() %}
```

I would expect:

Event 1: 14:00
Event 2: 15:00
Event 3: 16:00

but instead get something more random based I think on post date.

Suggestions welcome thank you!

UPDATE:

my biggest issue is actually being able to list by eventStart at all. Just using {{ eventStart }} reveals the current date. But if I try to boil down to just the hour, it's not a recognised way of ordering (even though it's just a set of numbers?)

So, I'm not sure where to head with this. I'm sure that if my start time was bundled in with the main date, all would be fine, but it makes the system a bit less obvious and flexible.

Here's what I've tried:

```
{% set completeeventlist = craft.entries.section('events') %}
{% for x in craft.entries(completeeventlist).order('eventDate') %}
<ul>
    {% set es = x.eventStart|date('H') %}
        {% for entry in craft.entries(x).order(es) %}
        <li>{{ entry.id }}{{ es }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Have you tried: `{% for entry in craft.entries.section('events').order('eventDate, eventStart').find() %}`

Comment: Tried that - throws an error CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'eventStart' in 'order clause'

Comment: eventStart is defiantly there, just ignored though as something to order from.

Comment: is it a custom fieldType from a plugin?

Comment: No, just a normal datetime field. It's a custom field, but it's just the time.

Comment: Also tried renaming the field. But that's not doing either.

Comment: What I can't work out here is if even though they maybe separate custom fields, they sort of are. Generally, if I just order by eventDate then it all defaults next to the hour set, but then there's some entries where this fall foul.

Possibly a way, if I could set just the hour - like {% set es = entry.eventStart|date('H') %} and then order.('es') could take out any datetime variables. Need to work this out though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Craft always saves a complete DateTime value to the database, even if you only make it set / show the time part of it in the Control Panel.

To ignore the date part (which in this case is set to the day you saved your entry) within the `order` parameter, you can make use of the [`time()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time) MySQL function:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').order('eventDate', 'time(eventStart)') %}
```

Comment: That "time()" function inside the order did the trick for me. Couldn't figure out why it couldn't order correctly from a time field.