# Sort entries by time part only of DateTime object

Tags: entry, datetime, filtering

I am trying to

1. filter and sort show entries by what time they begin
2. display the current show

I have two fields, `startTime`and `endTime`, and while Craft lets me display only the time part in the Control Panel, I can't filter entries in my template by the time part only.

Listing out entries:

```
{% set shows = craft.entries({
    section: 'shows',
    order: 'startTime asc',
    day: 'sunday',
}) %}
```

Displaying the current show:

```
{% set nowPlaying = craft.entries({
    section: 'shows',
    startTime: '<= ' ~ rightNow | date('c'),
    endTime: '>' ~ rightNow | date('c'),
    day: rightNow | date('l'),
}) %}
```

If I create all my show entries on the same day, filtering by the whole date is fine, but that's assuming

1. the times are never changed (thus updating the date)
2. I don't care to know what show is currently playing (because a show will only show up if I created it today).

I prefer not to reinvent the wheel by making a template-side sorting algorithm. Is there not a more elegant way to query just the time part in Craft filtering?

Comment: To clarify, `day` is a related category in the show entry.

Answer (score 2):

For those interested, I found out you can tell Craft to search the database for the time part only with the mySQL command time() ([Order entries by custom time field](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/6600/order-entries-by-custom-time-field)). For example:

```
{% set shows = craft.entries({
  section: 'shows',
  relatedTo: day.id,
  order: "time(startTime)",
}) %}
```

However, this sorts based on the absolute DB time (GMT time), so I substituted a conversion command for startTime:

```
{% set convertedStartTime = 'convert_tz(startTime,"+00:00","-06:00")' %}

{% set shows = craft.entries({
  section: 'shows',
  relatedTo: day.id,
  order: "time(#{convertedStartTime})",
}) %}
```

To my complete shock, this actually works. I could not find a similar way to search for the current show, so I first filtered entries by day, then ran a for-loop to find the current show (there's only ten shows or so per day):

```
{% set todaysShows = craft.entries({
  section: 'shows',
  relatedTo: today,
}) %}

{% for show in todaysShows if not done %}
    {% set start = show.startTime | date_modify('now') %}
    {% set end = show.endTime | date_modify('now') %}

    {% if now >= start and now < end %}
        {% set nowPlaying = show %}
        {% set done = true %}
    {% endif %}

  {% endfor %}`
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `day` field is a relation field you should search for your related entries with

```
{% set today = insertYourLogicToFetchTheCurrentDay %}
{# eg set todayName = "now"|date("l")#}
{# set today = craft.categories.title(todayName).first() #}
{% set showsToday = craft.entries.section('shows').relatedTo(today).find() %}
```

I don't really understand the second part of your question to be honest.

Is your `rightNow` a valid DateTime object? Normally I would do it like that

```
{% set startDate = now|date('U')%}
{% set endDate = now|date('U') %}
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('shows').startTime('>='~startDate).endDate('<=' ~ endDate).find() %}
```

**Edit**

Okay: based on our comments this solution could work (at least from my test) but this is just an example what you could do: i did no performance tests and it looks a little bit ugly since I did the "fast" way not the "I'm using craft styles and craft macros to make everything look good". You would have to extend it.

1. Go to [Pluginfactory](https://pluginfactory.io/) and fill out your fields. Turn on the light switch for `FieldTypes`
2. Download the files and move it to your Craft Plugins folder. You Plugin name should have the same name like your folder in plugins. So when you name your Plugin `MyPlugin` your folder is `/craft/plugins/myplugin/`
3. Go to the generated file `/fieldtypes` and overwrite these functions

   ```
   /**
    * Returns the input value as it should be saved to the database.
    *
    * @param mixed $value
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function prepValueFromPost($value)
   {
       return $value['hours'] . $value['minutes'];
   }

   /**
    * Prepares the field's value for use.
    *
    * @param mixed $value
    * @return mixed
    */
   public function prepValue($value)
   {
       if(empty($value)){
           return [
               'hours' => '00',
               'minutes'   => '00'
           ];
       }
       return [
           'hours' => substr($value, 0, 2),
           'minutes' => substr($value, 2, 4),
       ];
   }
   ```
4. There will be a template in your `/templates/field/...twig` folder change the input to something like this... I know this looks awful... you should style it and implement some logic to preselect fields and such

   ```
   <select name="{{ name ~ '[hours]' }}">
       <option value="00">00</option>
       <option value="01">01</option>
       <option value="02">02</option>
       <option value="03">03</option>
       <option value="04">04</option>
       <!-- and so on -->
   </select>
   selected = {{ values.hours }}

   <select name="{{ name ~ '[minutes]' }}">
       <option value="00">00</option>
       <option value="01">01</option>
       <option value="02">02</option>
       <option value="03">03</option>
       <option value="03">03</option>
       <!-- and so on -->
   </select>
   selected = {{ values.minutes }}
   ```
5. Change your two fields to the new field type. That way your db values will look like `0030` for 00:30 or `1340` for 13:40 you can now display the values in your frontend with

   ```
   {% for entry in craft.entries.section('shows') %}
       {{ entry.startTime.hours }}:{{ entry.startTime.minutes }}<br>
       {{ entry.enddate.hours }}:{{ entry.e.minutes }}<br>
       {% set startDate = entry.startTime.hours ~ entry.startTime.minutes %}
       {% set endDate = entry.endTime.hours ~ entry.endTime.minutes %}
       {% if startDate >= 0430 and endDate <= 1340   %}
           The show is between 04:30 and 13:40
       {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}
   ```

   Thus you can search via

   ```
   {% set now = "now"|date('H') ~ "now"|date('i') %}
   {% set entries = craft.entries.section('shows').relatedTo(day).find({
       'startdate': '>='~now,
       'enddate': '<='~now
   }) %}
   ```

Comment: Yes, rightNow is a dateTime object formatted as locale time (i.e. 4:00 PM). To clarify, these shows are date agnostic, meaning they happen at the same time every week, for instance 4-5 PM every Wednesday. (I turned the day into own category is because it makes the craft.entries search process easier.) Unfortunately, if I query for entries using just the time part (4:00 PM), Craft filtering assumes a full date (today at 4 PM), which throws off both the current show and and the sorting. Is that making more sense?

Comment: Ah now I see. I'm not sure if there is a good way to achieve this only with twig. I would probably build my custom `Query` in PHP and use a custom field type and no `date` field since you don't need the date anyway. But this can take some time to achieve if you are new to Craft and my experience is: most people don't want to use php. Let me know whether I should provide some code or not

Comment: Thanks Robin! That's what I was afraid of. I've not yet explored the dark ways of  PHP/custom plugin path yet because we push stuff out so quickly :P. I could do always do a regular number field and use military time, though that's less idiomatic from a client perspective. Appreciate your time!

Comment: Please check my edit. If you want to have only one select box for hours and minutes just remove the other select and input values like `0000, 0030, 0100` with the corresponding display values `00:00, 00:30, 01:00` and so on. You can inspect the Crafts html or use the macro to generate your inputs and make them look good

Comment: Thanks so much Robin! I found out afterwards that we couldn't go with the military time option, but I did find a neat solution I thought I'd post. See below.